# Find the value of $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{2x^2-1}{4x^4+1}\,{dx} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Find $ \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{2x^2-1}{4x^4+1}\,{dx}
>  $

I can find the primitive, but the fact that the answer is $0$ made me suspect there might be a way of getting answer without finding the primitive. I tried letting $x = 1/y$ but it didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: The indefinite integral evaluates to $\frac{1}{4} \log{ \frac{2x^2-2x +1}{2x^2 + 2x + 1}}$ which can now be seen to zero when evaluated at the limits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of substituting $x = \dfrac{1}{y}$, try substituting $x = \dfrac{1}{2y}$.

This gives you:

\begin{align*}I &= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2x^2-1}{4x^4+1}\,dx \\ &= \displaystyle\int_{\infty}^{0}\dfrac{\tfrac{1}{2y^2}-1}{\tfrac{1}{4y^4}+1} \cdot -\dfrac{1}{2y^2}\,dy \\ &= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\tfrac{1}{2y^2}-1}{\tfrac{1}{4y^4}+1} \cdot \dfrac{2y^2}{4y^4}\,dy \\ &= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1-2y^2}{4y^4+1}\,dy \\ &= -\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2y^2-1}{4y^4+1}\,dy \\ &= -I.\end{align*}

Since $I = -I$, we have $I = 0$.

Comment: May be $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 y}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$4x^4+1=(2x^2)^2+1^2=(2x^2+1)^2-(2x)^2=?$

Now use partial fraction decomposition